# Homotopy of parts of surface (?)

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, surfaces

Given surfaces $A$ and $B$ as below :

[image]

Note that $A$ is obtained by collapsing all boundary to a point (all purple lines and points to one point) and $B$ is obtained by collaping red part to one point, green part to another point and glue $a$ with $a'$.

It is clear that $A$ is homeomorphic to the $2-$sphere $S^2.$

I think $B$ should be homeomorphic to $S^2$ as well, but not sure how to prove this rigorously.

First, the collapsing map which collapses the yellow strip $l$ to a diagonal maps $B$ to $A$, but clearly not 1-1 so not a homoemorphism.

Technically, $B$ is like stretch one of the diagonals of $A$ to the strip $l$ in the interior of $B$. Perheps, the correct notion is $A$ and $B$ has the same homotopy type. But I am not sure since only part of $A$ is stretched, this seems to be a trouble in building a continuous homotopy $f,g$ so that $fg, gf \sim$ identity.

Anyone has suggestion to show that $B$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$ (i.e. closed surface with genus $0$) ?

Visulization of surfaces $A$ and $B$ : [image]

**Note : The right line on B should be colored green as well.**

Comment: Shouldn't the right edge of $B$ also be green?

Comment: Oh yes, I forget to color that.

Answer (score 1):

In $B$, the (left) blue polygon with a partially red border collapses to a disk (although it is perhaps easier to see this as a hemispherical cap on the end of the yellow tube) and so does the (right) blue polygon with partially green border.  So we should arrange for one cap-like region to become the left polygon.  Then an annulus around it becomes the yellow region, which we must cut to create the $a$ and $a'$ edges -- so we must cut the cap to get the red border.  Then there is very little choice for where the right polygon is...

[image: A with cuttings marked and yellow band indicated]

Cut along red/blue/green line.  Collapse purple boundary to a point (which point lands in the interior of the right blue polygon in $B$).  You obtain

[image: B deformed to just prior to obtaining A as per the previous diagram]

Here, the two red arcs and three red vertices in $B$ are explicit, the two green arcs and three green vertices are explicit (one is the purple arc, which is contracting to a green vertex) and the gluing along the two blue edges is explicit.

Comment: But the green and red need to shrink to two distinct points. Note that the identification on green and red are different from blue. All points in green shaded shrink to one point. Same for all point in red. But for blue, it is a usual side gluing. So I still doubt if this picture is the rigorous proof. It more like this picture is a homotopy version of B, by homotope red line to one point and homotope green line to another point.

Comment: @user117375 : The red arc and the green arc **are** homotopic to two distinct points.  The blue arc is between them.  I really can't make any sense of your objection: did you follow the instruction "Cut along red/blue/green line"?

Comment: Perhaps my picture showing sketch of two surfaces below is bad. The red line showing $B$ should not be red. The point should be the only thing colored red. Same for green, only point is colored green to show that all boundary was collapsed to only a point.

Comment: So the point is the picture you drew is not the surface $B$ itself, but some kind of homotopy of surface $B$ (on the actual surface $B$, the red line should be just a point. Same for the green line). Let say the surface you show is $B'$. So $B'$ is homoemorphic to $S^2$. The question is : Does $B$ homeomorphic to $B'$ ? So we can conclude that $B$ is $S^2$ as well. My problem is : I know that "some surfaces that are "homotopy (?)" to $B$ is clearly $S^2$, but how do we show that $B$ itself is $S^2$ ? Also, what is the correct notion between $B$ and $B'$ ? Same homotopy type ?

Comment: @user117375 : No.  The point is that the instruction "cut along ..." requires that you cut along ... .  I've done this for you now.